# matplotlib axis don't converge properly

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I make a graph using matplotlib and save it as a pdf. When I zoom in there is a gap where the x- and y-axis converge. Is there any way to get rid of this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.savefig('Scatter_Plot.pdf')
```

Unfortunately I can not upload pictures here - but here is a link:

http://de.tinypic.com/r/25gckcw/8

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Unless you show us your code (shortest example that shows the problem) we can't tell you what it is, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated matplotlib 1.3.1 -> 1.4.3
Now everything looks perfect!